# Does System Verilog support using functions to generate values for enums?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to define enums for a bunch of variables part of a typedef and I was wondering if the values for these enums could come from a function?

```
typedef enum logic [4:0] {
START  =  myfunc(2'b00),
PROC   =  myfunc(2'b01),
STOP   =  myfunc(2'b10),
REPORT =  myfunc(2'b11)
} x;

x stream1
```

where myfunc is a function that returns a 5 bit value for the supplied 2 bit argument.

Is this possible?

I tried running with above code in my simulator and it gave me an error.

Comment: Show us a complete example and the error you are getting. My example works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the function is a *constant* function which could be evaluated at elaboration time, you can do it. Here is an example:

```
module test();
  parameter bit[3:0] ext = 3'b101;
  
  function bit[4:0] myfunc(bit[1:0]in);
    return {ext, ~in};
  endfunction
  typedef enum logic [4:0] {
    START  =  myfunc(2'b00),
    PROC   =  myfunc(2'b01),
    STOP   =  myfunc(2'b10),
    REPORT =  myfunc(2'b11)
  } x_t;
  //x_t x;
  
  initial begin
    $display("%s: %b", START, START);
    $display("%s: %b", PROC, PROC);
 end
endmodule
```

Note: $display %s of a enum label as a string is not standard works in vcs and questa, but not in cadence.